# How do I make my particles.js layer behind my buttons and text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add my particles.JS layer behind my main stuff, for example my buttons and text are in front of the layer so the buttons can be clicked on/redirectable.

Here's my JSFiddle live demo to show what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/c2qp3jkf/

````
<div id="particles-js"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="particles.js">
    </script>
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the HTML part; all elements must be inside the `<div id="particles-js"></div>` container.

*NOT:* I compressed it as I didn't change the JavaScript and CSS parts. There are problems with the style applied to the page; if you can't solve the problems, you can create a *new question*.

```js
particlesJS("particles-js",{particles:{number:{value:100,density:{enable:!0,value_area:800}},color:{value:"#ffffff"},shape:{type:"circle",stroke:{width:0,color:"#00ff00"},polygon:{nb_sides:5},image:{src:"img/github.svg",width:100,height:100}},opacity:{value:.5,random:!1,anim:{enable:!1,speed:1,opacity_min:.1,sync:!1}},size:{value:3,random:!0,anim:{enable:!1,speed:40,size_min:.1,sync:!1}},line_linked:{enable:!0,distance:150,color:"#ffffff",opacity:.4,width:1},move:{enable:!0,speed:4,direction:"none",random:!0,straight:!1,out_mode:"out",bounce:!1,attract:{enable:!1,rotateX:600,rotateY:1200}}},interactivity:{detect_on:"canvas",events:{onhover:{enable:!1,mode:"grab"},onclick:{enable:!1,mode:"push"},resize:!1},modes:{grab:{distance:140,line_linked:{opacity:1}},bubble:{distance:400,size:40,duration:2,opacity:8,speed:3},repulse:{distance:200,duration:.4},push:{particles_nb:5},remove:{particles_nb:2}}},retina_detect:!0});
```

```css
body{background-color:#fff;font-family:monospace}.border-button{border:solid 2.5px #000;transition:border-width .6s linear;border-radius:20px;background-color:transparent;padding:2px 7px;font-size:11px;cursor:pointer;display:inline-block}.btn:hover{background:rgba(238,238,238,0.48)}.fourofour{color:#000}.border-button{border:solid 2.5px #000;transition:border-width .4s linear}.border-button:hover{border-width:3.5px}*{margin:0;padding:0}body{background:#000}canvas{display:block}#particles-js{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns#">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>arr3</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Darkheart_Gear.ico">
      <meta property="og:title" content="arr3.ml" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.arr3.gq" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.arr3.ml/Darkheart_Gear.ico" />
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
      <style>body,html{margin:0;padding:0;width:100vw;height:100vh;background:linear-gradient(124deg,#ff2400,#e81d1d,#e8b71d,#e3e81d,#1de840,#1ddde8,#2b1de8,#dd00f3,#dd00f3);background-size:1800% 1800%;font-family:monospace;color:#000;image-rendering:pixelated;scrollbar-width:none;overflow:none;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column;-webkit-animation:rainbow 18s ease infinite;-z-animation:rainbow 18s ease infinite;-o-animation:rainbow 18s ease infinite;animation:rainbow 18s ease infinite}::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none}iframe{width:100vw;height:100vh;border:none;margin:0;padding:0;display:block}@-webkit-keyframes rainbow{0%{background-position:0 82%}50%{background-position:100% 19%}100%{background-position:0 82%}}@-moz-keyframes rainbow{0%{background-position:0 82%}50%{background-position:100% 19%}100%{background-position:0 82%}}@-o-keyframes rainbow{0%{background-position:0 82%}50%{background-position:100% 19%}100%{background-position:0 82%}}@keyframes rainbow{0%{background-position:0 82%}50%{background-position:100% 19%}100%{background-position:0 82%}}h2{padding:1em 2em;margin:.25em}h5{padding:1em 2em;margin:.25em}.button-wrap{width:25%;display:flex;justify-content:space-around}</style>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- All items must be inside the container below. -->
   <div id="particles-js">
      <section class="seperator-wrapper">
         <div class="seperator gradient">
         </div>
      </section>
      <h2 class="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft" style="font-family:monospace; font-weight: 500;font-style: normal; text-align:center; color:Black">arr3</h2>
      <h4 style="font-family:monospace; font weight: 500; font-style: normal; text-align:center; color:Black"> I love coding.</h4>
      <br>
      <button onclick="location.href = 'info.html'"
         style="font-family:monospace; font-weight: 500; font-style: normal; text-align:center; color:black" class="border-button">Want to learn more?</button>
      <br>
      <div class="button-wrap">
         <button onclick="location.href = 'mobydick.html'"
            style="font-family:monospace; font-weight: 500; font-style: normal; text-align:center; color:black" class="border-button">Read Moby Dick</button>
         <br>
         <button onclick="location.href = 'hmrkey.html'"
            style="font-family:monospace; font-weight: 500; font-style: normal; text-align:center; color:black" class="border-button">HammerHead Key</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want my text and buttons to be in the center. Thanks for helping me out though!

Comment: The code is not clean and there are two conflicting style definitions. After you clear your code, you can ask a new question.

Comment: Alright, Ill make sure to do that

Answer (score 0):

Put your content items in a container `<div>` and set your `z-index` higher than a `z-index` you set for your particles-js `<div>`.